# Backup SanDisk Ultra 32GB using Win32DiskImager or Roadkill

Tags: sd-card, backup, win32diskimager

I formatted the SD card using Windows Vista and SD Formatter. Then I copied NOOBs files, inserted it into the PI3 and installed all my softare (Raspberry...). The system works but I am unable to backup the SD card on my Windows PC using either Win32DiskImageer or Roadkill. Even Windows File explorer cant open the SD drive and from all software I get asked if I want to format the drive.

When I first installed my PI3 using Win32DiskImager and Raspberry I could back up from time to time but in the end I tried it again and had the same problem as now.
That was with a 16 GB card.

What could possibly cause that and how do I get a backup onto my Windows PC done ?

Comment: What happens when you try and read the image file from the SD card using Win32DiskImager? Are there any error messages or does the drive not show up at all in the drop down list?

Comment: Windows File Explorer sees the drive and says: You need to format the disk X: before you can use it.

Comment: Win32Imager sees the drive letter but no image file to choose from. When I say Browse in File folder I get the same Windows msg that I need to format the drive before ready to use

Comment: Roadkil says physical disk 2 not ready

Comment: Win32 Disk Imager will not see an image file, when you open the file dialogue you are selecting the path and name that you want to write the image of the entire disk to. The data on the SD card is not stored as an image. See [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=239331) guide

Comment: Waoh you are right, I got confused because I didnt see the 32 GB and only 1.49GB but now it works !!

Comment: Okay I have added that as an official answer, if you want to accept that as the answer it could help other people in the future. Also when you write the OS to the SD card it created two partitions, windows explorer will only see the first partition which is the 1.49GB one, you can use other tools to see them both.

Answer (score 0):

> Win32Imager sees the drive letter but no image file to choose from. When I say Browse in File folder I get the same Windows msg that I need to format the drive before ready to use

I answered this in the comments

> Win32 Disk Imager will not see an image file, when you open the file dialogue you are selecting the path and name that you want to write the image of the entire disk to. The data on the SD card is not stored as an image. See [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=239331) guide